# Collection data not appearing in models after being posted. (Includes collections of collections.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a PersonEditorModel that contains a list of people that I want represented in the editor. I have a collection of Person objects that contains a collection of Address objects. I want to render text boxes for all of these so that the user can edit names and address associated with those names.

```
class PersonEditorModel 
{
    public List<Person> People;
}

class Person 
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Address> Addresses;
}

class Address
{
    public string Value;
}
```

I'm generating a form for editing the addresses and the names associated with them. It's using Ajax.BeginForm because this is a simplified example derived from a problem I'm having in a bigger app where the form updates a different part of the page using Ajax to get a result.

In the base form's cshtml:

```
@model Models.PersonEditorModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.People)
        <button type="submit">Commit Changes</button>
    </div>
}
```

Person.cshtml:

```
@model Models.Person
<div> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </div>
<div> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Addresses) </div>
```

Address.cshtml:

```
@model Models.Address
<div> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value) </div>
```

The controller's method for the action:

```
public ActionResult Update(List<Person> people) { /* snip */ }
```

When I submit this form, a breakpoint placed immediately within Update() shows that "people" is a list of the right length but it contains absolutely no data--all the addresses are empty strings, even though the form data as appears in Request.Form looks correct.

What could be causing such a problem and what would be an idiomatic MVC way to solve this issue?

NOTE: This is a simplified example of some behavior I'm seeing in a more complex app. I think I've captured the essence of the issue here, but there may be some other unknown complicating factor. Let me know what could complicate this to cause the issue I'm seeing and I'll try to provide whatever additional details I can.

I've tried making Update take a PersonEditorModel parameter instead, but that gets absolutely no data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Address
{
    public string Value;
}
```

should be:

```
class Address
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The default model binder works with properties, not fields.

Also make sure the generated input field names respect the [standard convention](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Since I've always used fields when I'd otherwise use properties without special get or set logic, I mentally conflate properties with default get and set with public fields. This assumption led me to mentally skipping over the fact that info about model binding talks about properties and not fields. My practice of using fields so often is probably a bad one that I should rectify.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have at least two problems here, both model-related.  First is that the object being posted to your call is built automagically based upon the ids of input elements in the generated form. For example to extract a property called PersonName, there would need to be a tag somewhere resembling

```
<input type='whatever' id='PersonName' />
```

As such, these properties must be able to be represented via such an input.

The second problem stems from this first.  Using MVC's built in ajax forms (which are limited compared to AJAX in general (and in jQuery)), there is no way (that I know of, at least) to define any collections, but especially not something as generic as a list.  To do this using MVC's AJAX, you would probably need to implement an editor for one person/user at a time and submit that data (with a singular or enumerated number of addresses) passed back.

Also, you might want to reconsider updating a whole set of people via one AJAX call.  The dynamic nature of AJAX better lends itself to smaller, more frequent updates.

Comment: I have neither of those problems. This is a simplified example which doesn't justify the use of AJAX, but I included it in my simplified example because I thought it may have some bearing on the issue at hand. The inputs are already generated for me through the use of @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Thing), so if that were being generated wrong it'd be an issue with TextBoxFor/EditorFor and not me.